# SQL query to get the source of a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm using a DB2 database and I'm hoping for a query which will iterate over all stored procedures in a single database and print out the source code of each. No fancy formatting or performance requirements.

The reason for this (in case there's a better way of doing it) is I'm trying to track down usages of a particular table in our stored procs, so I want to be able to do a simple text search through all of them.

Also, I've got access to SQuirreL SQL client if anyone knows of a way via that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, figured it out. For other's reference:

```
select ROUTINENAME, TEXT from syscat.routines
where definer not in ('SYSIBM') AND ROUTINESCHEMA='databaseName'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but your answer started me on the right track. We are also using DB2, but don't have syscat.routines visible to us. However we do have SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES and that allows similar by doing

```
SELECT SCHEMA,
       NAME,
       TEXT
FROM SYSIBM.SYSROUTINES
WHERE SCHEMA = '<SCHEMA>'
  and NAME = '<NAME>'
FOR FETCH ONLY WITH UR;
```